# how to resolve DllNotFoundException using dllimport? (Mono Vb)

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, .net

I'm new to Unix/Linux/Ubuntu.

I'm using Mono with VB and I'm trying to use the methods from a library via DllImport (CliSiTef32I.dll / libclisitef.so) however it keeps giving me DllNotFoundException

Searching in foruns I've tried a few things already:

- ld.so.conf with the paths containing the libraries
- dllMap in the project.exe.config

Any help is appreciated.

My Code: (I tried importing with the .Dll and the .SO directly, neither worked)

C#

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SitefCSharp

{

static class MdlTEF

{

[DllImport("CliSiTef32I.dll")] // [DllImport("libclisitef.so")]    
private static extern int ConfiguraIntSiTefInterativo(string EndSitef, string IdLoja, string IdTerminal, Int16 Reservado);

        static void Main()
        {
            int sts = 0;
            try
            {
                sts = ConfiguraIntSiTefInterativo("", "", "", 0);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.ToString();
                //the exception is System.DllNotFoundException at (wrapper managed-to-native)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

VB

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction


Public Module EmptyClass

    Public Sub Main()
    Dim sts as Integer
    Try
        sts = ConfiguraIntSiTefInterativo("", "", "", 0)
    Catch ex as Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    End Sub

    Public Declare Function ConfiguraIntSiTefInterativo Lib "libclisitef.so" (ByVal EndSiTef As String, ByVal IdLoja As String, ByVal IdTerminal As String, ByVal Reservado As Int16) As Int32
    'Public Declare Function ConfiguraIntSiTefInterativo Lib "CliSiTef32I.dll" (ByVal EndSiTef As String, ByVal IdLoja As String, ByVal IdTerminal As String, ByVal Reservado As Int16) As Int32

End Module
```

//dll map in the project.exe.config file

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="CliSiTef32I.dll" target="libclisitef.so"/>
</configuration>
```

//My ld.so.conf file... I tried putting the libraries in all those paths

```
/home/pdv/Projetos/PDV/kaiser/clisitef
/lib
/lib64
/usr/lib
/usr/lib64
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib64
/home/pdv/Projects/TesteTef/TesteTef/bin/Debug
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem using mono_log_level=debug
it wasnt able to load a 32bit dll, I tried the 64 version and it worked!